# What is the density of distribution which is obtained by acting with a Mobius transformation on the unit disc with uniform distribuition?

Tags: complex-analysis, statistics, uniform-distribution, mobius-transformation

So, I have given a Mobius transformation that preserves unit disc. In unit disc I have uniform distribution (distribution that has constant density). I have to act with this Mobius transformation on this uniform distribution. What will I get?What density it will have?

Can anybody please help me with this? Or at least tell me which literature available on internet I should look that would give me the best answer on this...
Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A map $z\to f(z)$ expands the area by a factor $|f'(z)|^2$. Thus the density at $f(z)$ is proportional to $\frac1{|f'(z)|^2}$. Equivalently, the density at $w$ is proportional to $|{f^{-1}}'(w)|^2$.

Comment: Thank you! And how I can apply with a Mobius transormation that preserves unit disc on such a disc with uniform distribution?

Comment: @Tota: I'm afraid I don't understand the question. The uniform distribution on the unit disk has density $\frac1\pi$, and you transform that as described in the answer. If you want to know more than that, you're going to have to ask a more specific question. By the way, you're misspelling the transformation. The name is "Möbius", with an 'ö', which represents a completely different sound than an 'o' and only has historical connections to the 'o' it resembles graphically.

Comment: I am sorry that I wasn't good enough on explaining my question.It's because English is not my native language and I learned it just in school.I'll try to explain it one more time...I have given a Möbius transformation that preserves unit disc.I should act with this function on unit disc with uniform distribution.I need to find out what will I get.What kind of distribution?What density it will have? Thank you!

Comment: @Tota: I don't understand the concept of "acting on the unit disc with a distribution". As far as I understand the question, you have random variable that is uniformly distributed on the unit disk, you apply a Möbius transformation to this random variable, and you want to know the resulting density on the unit disk. This is just $\frac1\pi|{f^{-1}}'(w)|^2$, as derived in the answer. I'm afraid I don't know what more to say about it.

Comment: Ok,thank you!Would you send me any link of a book or something in wich I can read a little more about this?I'm trying to search it but I think that I'm not  'translating ' my question good so that I can find something that I'm exactly looking for...Sorry:)

Comment: @Tota: Unfortuantely I'm not good at recommending books; I don't have many math books; I usually read up on these things on Wikipedia and the like. You can ask a new question asking about that, though. There are tags [tag:reference-request] and [tag:book-recommendation] for that sort of question.